# Javascript canvas animation with initial delay

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am using requestAnimationFrame in my canvas animation, but I would like to delay the animation for 3 seconds before it starts. I have placed

```
setTimeout(draw(), 3000);
```

in many places in my code. Some noted in the comments in the code below:

```
MyApp.prototype._animation = function() {

var cvs = document.querySelector("#animation");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = cvs.width;
var canvasHeight = cvs.height;

var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                        window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

// tried setTimeout here

function draw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  ctx.fillRect(100+posX,0,7,canvasHeight); //pole

  var instrument = new Path2D();
  instrument.moveTo(65+posX,50+posY);
  instrument.lineTo(100+posX,50+posY);
  instrument.lineTo(100+posX, 10+posY);
  instrument.lineTo(65+posX, 10+posY);
  instrument.arc(65+posX,30+posY, 20, Math.PI/2, 3*Math.PI/2, false);
  instrument.closePath();

  var circle = new Path2D();
  circle.arc(65+posX, 30+posY, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";

  ctx.fill(instrument);
  ctx.fill(circle);

  if (posY < 50){
      posY += 1;
  } else {
      posX += 1;
  };

  if (posX > 200) {
    return;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

}

// tried setTimeout here
draw();

};
```

I am trying to figure out how to use setTimeout in this case in order to delay the start of the animation.

EDIT: I am trying to figure out WHERE to place setTimeout in this method in order to initially delay the animation.

Comment: `setTimeout(draw, 3000);` or `setTimeout(function() { draw() }, 3000);`

Comment: I will use that, but I am wondering where to put it in the method.

Comment: It should work there. Though you need to wait for the document to be loaded.

Comment: $(function() {  //All your code in here  });    Which is the jQuery shortcut to document.onload

Comment: It does not work in those two places indicated in my code. Also, the document is definitely loaded by the time it gets to this place in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of your script where you call `draw()`, replace that with:

```
// Note: no parens in the draw
window.setTimeout(draw,3000);
```